# How to get in which criteria the range falls using sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Code:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempMaster','U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempMaster

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTransaction','U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TempTransaction

CREATE TABLE #TempMaster
(
Sno INT IDENTITY(1,1),
RangeDesc VARCHAR(100),
RangeFromValue INT,
RangeToValue INT
)

CREATE TABLE #TempTransaction
(
Sno INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[Values] INT
)

INSERT INTO #TempMaster(RangeDesc,RangeFromValue,RangeToValue)
SELECT * FROM (VALUES('Type A',1,10),('Type B',11,20),('Type C',21,30)) AS T(RangeDesc,RangeFromValue,RangeToValue)



INSERT INTO #TempTransaction([Values])
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 15
UNION ALL
SELECT 5



SELECT * FROM #TempMaster
SELECT * FROM #TempTransaction
```

Please anyone help me to get a this kind of a solution based on which range the value falls.
I want to get a range description and write down a query for a below output. Thanks in advance.

```
-------------------------------
sno     Values      RangeDesc
-------------------------------
1       1           Type A
2       15          Type B
3       5           Type A
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `left join` based on range values.

```
select t1.Sno, t1.[Values], t2.RangeDesc
from #TempTransaction t1
left join #TempMaster  t2 on t1.[Values] between t2.RangeFromValue and t2.RangeToValue
```